# Working with the data from LinQ SQL query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

Using VS 2013 (VB) and SQL server 2016.

I have linQ query that returns two columns from a database.  The query is as follows.

```
        Dim val = (From value In db.ngc_flowTypes
               Where value.defaultValue IsNot Nothing
               Select value.flowName, value.defaultValue)
```

The data it returns is a as follows.

[image: result set from sql table]

I want to iterate through each row of the results and pass the values to certain variables.  A ForEach statement doesnt seem to work as it just runs through once.  I am sure this must be easy but I ont quite understand it.  Am I getting the data returned in the best way via my query?  Can I transpose the data to a data table in VB? so I can work with it easier?

The end result I want is string for each flow name with its corresponding default value (along with some other text).  So something like this.

```
dim strsubmission as string = flowName + " has a value of " + defaultValue
```

Comment: _" A ForEach statement doesnt seem to work as it just runs through once."_ What? How many times do you want to iterate through them? Where is your attempt at using `ForEach`?

Comment: As there are four results returned I would assume it would run through four times.  eg for each result in val 'do something  next

Comment: Did you try `select flowName + " has a value of " + defaultValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dim val = (From value In db.ngc_flowTypes
           Where value.defaultValue IsNot Nothing
           Select value).ToDictionary(Function(key) key.flowName, 
                                      Function(value) value.defaultValue)
```

This will actually execute the SQL of the linq on the database (approx. `Select * From ngc_flowTypes Where defaultValue Is Not NULL`), traverse each record into a key/value pair (`flowName`, `defaultValue`) and put it into a in-memory dictionary variable (`val`).

After that you can do whatever you like with the dictionary.

```
 For Each flowName In val.Keys
      Console.WriteLine("{0} has a value of {1}", flowName, val(flowName))
 Next
```

**Edit**:
This will only work as long `flowName` is unique in table `ngc_flowTypes`